# Semicosimplicial totalization

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

Can somebody help me with a reference showing that the homotopy semicosimplicial totalization of a cosimplicial space is homotopy equivalent to its usual homotopy totalization? Is it because the inclusion of the semisimplicial category into the simplicial category is a homotopy left cofinal functor?

Comment: Having thought a little bit I proved that the inclusion of the semisimplicial category to the simplicial category is a homotopy left cofinal functor. But it must be a very standard thing and written somewhere. Can somebody help me with a reference? 

Answer (score 2):

I agree this should be standard, but I've only seen the proof in one place. See Lemma 6.5.3.7 of Lurie's Higher Topos Theory.

Comment: Hi Hiro! Glad to hear from you and thanks for your reference. But of course this thing is older than Lurie:
E. Dror, W. G. Dwyer. A long homology localization tower. Comment. Math. Helv. 52 (1977), no. 2, 185210.